# Values from Analytics different in a table than a time series

Tags: looker-studio

I'm having an issue where the figures pulled from Analytics are different in a table format than the time series.

As you can see in the image below the 'Nutzer' (user) value in the table for Sep 2019 is 6692 but on the time series is 7789. This then affects the calculated values for 'Umsatz pro Nutzer'.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to stop it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the most likely answer is that there is a filter active on one or both of the objects that is altering the displayed data.

To test this out, create a copy of the sheet and delete the chart. Then make a copy of your table and change it to a time series using the chart options. I just did this process using a connection to the GA property for our mobile app and I see identical data for users for both the table and the time series.

Comment: Hey, there's no filters on either of them apart from the date range.